# Could water physically makeup the core of a planet or otherwise large celestial mass?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, water, earth

Knowing very little about the nature of water, wondering how it might behave at the centre of a planet or centre of an another massive gravitational body.

Could water take such pressures or might it break into separate hydrogen and oxygen to find something more accommodating for the pressure exerted, if such atmosphere would allow the volume even?

Finally, bonus points: could triple points in water play a role in keeping temperatures low under high pressures via fluid thermodynamics, ultimately leading out of two jets at the poles, forcing itself into an efficient helix leading back to the surface?

Would it be physically possible that the earth could sustain itself with water at it's core?

Update:
This question has been asked and answered. The answer is possibly. At least according to: 
[Physics Question 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/could-there-be-a-body-of-water-the-size-of-a-planet)
and
[Physics Question 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61016/what-is-the-largest-sphere-of-liquid-water-that-could-exist-in-space-held-togeth)

I'm just surprised that if it's true Earth can be supported by a water core, via exotic ices at super high pressures, that the community didn't jump to any conclusions. Better to leave such to philosophers, eh? ;)

Comment: The core will contain the densest component of the body. The core would only be ice if the body was made up exclusively of water. The Earth cannot have a core made of ice because the metal and rock is denser and would displace it.

Comment: so metal and rock have to be denser than water, even at extreme pressures?

Comment: They are denser than water for all pressures at we have done experiments. There is no obvious reason why water should become denser as the pressure is increased.

Comment: we're talking about the nature of water under really high pressures.. the charts show water as ice at such pressure, i think the many exotic flavours of ice continually compact their lattice structure to essentially compress itself.

Comment: Yes, but the pressure would also compress the metal and rock so they would get denser too.

Comment: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7491/full/507174a.html

Comment: @JohnRennie might the metal not begin to compress further until all the space (water) compresses to an equilateral geometry? if so maybe the water would have an advantage via hydrogen bonding to homogenize/unify

Comment: @Bernhard thanks this story made me think if we're finding reserves of water on so many levels, why would we assume it's not possible to have a core of it too.. likely as a solution for tiny conductive molecules that run the dynamo in a fluid-thermodynamic way

Comment: @irth Read carefully, there is not litterally an ocean under water.

Comment: I get that the article isn't implying that per se but could it work nonetheless?

Comment: or to simplify the question, is there a limit to how much pressure water can physically take, and if there is a limit, what happens?

Comment: Under *extreme* pressure, the water would become a black hole.  But by then it has ceased to be water, I suppose.

Comment: @MrWonderful any thoughts to how a relatively small black hole should behave if it were surrounded by much more mass?

Comment: @MrWonderful and could you possibly explain how a black hole develops from pressure if that could relate into the question?

Comment: @irth: Not being a theoretical physicist, I'd be reluctant to hypothesize how matter becomes a black hole.  On the other hand, I'm be happy to share this link with you that I believe you'll find interesting...  http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2007/05/070517-hot-planet_2.html